# Editing a custom field of a Managed package object

Tags: managed-package, custom-field

I am using an app deployed using a managed package.
I've added a custom field to one of the package's custom objects.
When I'm trying to edit this new field I see it does not appear on the detail page edit mode (It is visible only on the view mode).

Is there any config param I need to change in order to be able to edit this new field?

Answer (score 1):

It is likely field level security or a setting on the field layout item. First find your field on the object and click the View Field Accessibility and Set Field-Level Security buttons to review. Also click the config icon next to the field in the Layout and check its properties.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the Edit button was overridden to display a custom VF page.
When I canceled the override it solved the problem.

Comment: Ah I see, you where not seeing the standard UI, doh! :)

Comment: Removed the 'chatty' part of this answer. But for the record Dedo tried Andrew Fawcett's solution and thanked him for it before discovering this.